# Ошибка при навигации vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Когда подключаю `vue-router` навигация не работает, выдает вот такие ошибки в консоли Chrome:

```
[vue-router] uncaught error during route navigation:
TypeError: Cannot set property props of #<Object> which has only a getter
```

[image: скриншот ошибок]

Вот так я создаю роутер:

```
var router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    base: '/account/',
    linkActiveClass: 'active',
    meta: {
        permission: 'any',
        fail: '/',
    },
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/contribution',
            component: contribution,
            meta: {
                permission: 'any',
                fail: '/',
            },
        },
        {
            path: '/deposits',
            component: deposits,
            meta: {
                permission: 'any',
                fail: '/',
            },
        },
        {
            path: '/withdraw',
            component: withdraw,
            meta: {
                permission: 'any',
                fail: '/',
            },
        },
        {
            path: '/settings',
            component: settings,
            meta: {
                permission: 'any',
                fail: '/',
            },
        }
    ]
});
```

Вот так добавляю его:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router: router,
    ....
    ....
```

Нашел похожую ошибку на GitHub, там предлагали добавить метаданные к роутам, мне это не помогло. В чем может быть ошибка и как ее исправить?